# Cannot convert file to string for very large file?

Tags: java, file

I have tried to implement a bufferedreader in order to convert a .txt file, specifically the Iliad to a string.  I have tested small files and they have worked but the larger do not. When I attempt to print fileString after the while loop it finished, no output is shown. Here's my code.

```
String fileString = "";
    String line = "";
    char readChar;

    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            fileString = fileString + line;System.out.println(fileString);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }System.out.println(fileString);
```

Comment: Does the total number of characters exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: No errors at all?  What does "not work" in this context?

Comment: Does it finish running? While it looks simple, this method of creating very large strings is *very* inefficient

Comment: The program does finish running, there are no errors and the file has fewer than Integer_MAX_VALUE characters.

Comment: And by not work I mean that there is no visible output for the larger file.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that Strings are immutable in java. This means that the way you are constructing the String from by `+` is extremely inefficient and resource costly.

You can use either StringBuilder or StringBuffer. In my example I use StringBuilder since it does not seem that you need to worry about synchronization.

```
    StringBuilder fileString = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        char readChar;

        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                fileString.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
System.out.println(fileString.toString());
```

Try this. Although, I am not sure whether println function will be able to print the whole string.

Comment: I have implemented it this way and, while the program runs faster, the print command yields no result for the large file.

Comment: As mentioned in @SamFisher83's last line, since the file is too large it would most likely not be able to print (though I would expect a memory crash if you tried to print to console). You could always print the file line by line to the screen (which is a heavy operation). Though why do you need to print to screen?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing string concatenation the slow way. The very slow way. Use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.

It has exactly nothing to do with `BufferedReader` whatsoever, as a simple test will show: remove the code in the body of the loop.